# What is the least verbose way of doing a nested for loop?

Tags: ruby, for-loop, nested

I'm trying to do repeat a code block, but have something happen every 5th time.

In English:

```
Do this 30 times, every 5th time take an additional step
```

My Ruby so far:

```
  6.times do
     5.times do
        #standard step
       end
     #perform additional step
   end
```

but I wondered if there was a clever way to do it?

Comment: Be careful chasing the "less verbose" car. Instead, you want elegant, which translates into simple, short and very understandable and results in good throughput and easier maintenance. And, less verbose does not necessarily translate to faster; Only benchmarking will tell you that.

Comment: verbose, to me, is inelegant. Thus, less verbose is more elegant.

Comment: Well, you are certainly welcome to redefine the meaning of "elegant" for your own use, however that term encompasses much more than the number of characters in a statement, and will run afoul of how many others understand and use "elegant".

Comment: I am not sure what you are getting at. It is clear to me that we both want the same thing. We have just said it differently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

mostly you do "every nth time" problems with a modulo like this:

```
30.times do |n|
  # standard step
  if n % 5 == 0
    puts n # extra step
  end
end
```

Comment: @Mild Fuzz: Since there wasn't that much code to start with, there wasn't much to remove. The main advantage here is, that it's simpler and small changes (40 times, every 8th time) can be implemented with less thinking. The standard step & extra step part somehow requires two independent areas.